# Unable to publish Liferay Pages to Remote Live Boxes

Tags: java, spring, liferay, liferay-7

Iam having a Author(with 1 database) and Remote Live(with 1 database) setup in Liferay 7.1.

I was publishing all public pages one by one to remote live boxes which was successful. suddenly I started getting the below error,

```
 The publication process did not start due to validation errors.
 The model.resource.com.liferay.site.model.adapter.StagedGroup 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" 
default-locale="en_US"><Name language-id="en_US">Guest</Name></root> could 
not be imported because of the following error: 
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by 
another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): 
[com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl#296619].
```

After this error I couldn't publish any pages, Iam keep on getting the same error.

If anyone can guide me on how to solve the issue it will be greatly helpful. Iam really struggling with this error.

Attached screenshot as well.
[image]

Comment: Please [don't crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823) - also: Stackoverflow is the right place when you're looking for coding problems, not with configuration or general software functionality. Unless you do show the code you use, this question is off-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: @OlafKock Understood. I won't happen again. Btw can you guide me on the above issue please, I am struggling with this for a long time.